# Sending multiple email from codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hi friends i am creating newsletter in codeigniter. Is there a way to send multiple email with CI email lib or should i use third party ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the Email Class, something like:

```
foreach ($list as $name => $address)
{
    $this->email->clear();

    $this->email->to($address);
    $this->email->from('your@example.com');
    $this->email->subject('Here is your info '.$name);
    $this->email->message('Hi '.$name.' Here is the info you requested.');
    $this->email->send();
}
```

would work. (Straight from the docs). It depends on how many addresses you have, and any constraints such as server/mail queue processing/script time out etc

I'm not personally aware of a 3rd party CI newsletter plugin/library but i haven't looked too hard.

Answer (score 5):

Straight from the manual…

```
$this->email->to()
```

Sets the email address(s) of the recipient(s). Can be a single email, a comma-delimited list or an array:

```
$this->email->to('someone@example.com'); 
$this->email->to('one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com'); 
$list = array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com');
$this->email->to($list);
```