# Send a mail to multiple recipients in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

In my controller there is a code for sending email to one recipient, But I want to send mail to multiple recipients. Not use cc,bcc or direct assignment. I want to enter comma separated mail ids through the front end

how to take each mail id in comma separated form?

**Controller:**

```
public function shopshare($userid,$shopname,$shop_id)
{
    $from_email=$this->input->post('from_email');
    $to_email=$this->input->post('to_email');
    $subject_url=$this->input->post('url');
    $message=$this->input->post('message');
    $this->email->from($from_email);
    $this->email->to($to_email); 
    $this->email->subject($url);
    $this->email->message($message);    
    $this->email->send();

    redirect(base_url().'shop/shopDetail/'.$shop_id.'/'.$shopname);
}
```

**View:**

```
<label>
    <span>To:</span>
    <input id="to_email" type="text" name="to_email[]" placeholder="To Email Address">
</label>
```

Comment: this->email->to('abc@gmail.com','xyz@gmail.com');

Comment: not like this.i want to  enter each id in view through the textbox

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194618/sending-mail-to-multiple-recipients-with-sendgrid-and-codeigniter

Comment: not that way..enter email ids through front end

Comment: @Star If you enter email ids through front end then as per your code you pass array so rest of the answer provide is true if not then you need like multiselect or any other way to pass email array.

Comment: i put it as array in view.How to take each value in controller

Comment: if you have googled it for once, you'll find this on top 3 links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer using the code below

```
    public function shopshare($userid, $shopname, $shop_id)
    {
         $from_email = $this->input->post('from_email');
         $to_email = $this->input->post('to_email');
         $to_mail = explode(',', $to_email);
         $mail_count= count($to_mail);
         for($i=0;$i<$mail_count;$i++)
         {
             $mail_id = TRIM($to_mail[$i]);
             $subject_url = $this->input->post('url');
             $message = $this->input->post('message');
             $this->email->from($from_email);
             $this->email->to($mail_id);
             $this->email->subject($url);
             $this->email->message($message);
             $this->email->send();
             $this->email->clear();
        }
        redirect(base_url() . 'shop/shopDetail/' . $shop_id . '/' . $shopname);
    }
```

Comment: this code satisfy all my needs..i post this for future reference

Comment: i think @php-coder's answer will do the same without the loop, have you tried it?

Comment: This is not correct in terms of performance. Consider sending a hundred thousand emails in a loop!

Answer (score 6):

You can use array of recipients, or if they stored in database you can retrieve and store all again in array and than implode them by ','.

for example if you create array or get array result from database,

```
 $recipients = Array('user1@gmail.com','user2@gmail.com''user3@gmail.com');

     this->email->to(implode(', ', $recipients));
```

Or also can give multiple emails as it is

```
this->email->to('user1@gmail.com','user2@gmail.com''user3@gmail.com');
```

This will send you multiple mail.

**EDIT as per Robins Comment**

as you comment that you want to have multiple entry from front-end text box,

if it is a single text box you can ask user to have multiple email by ',' separate.

```
 $mails = $this->input->post('email');

 this->email->to($mails);
```

if you have multiple text boxes give all text boxes same name like 'email[]'

```
 $mails = $this->input->post('email');

 this->email->to(implode(', ', $mails));
```

Comment: i want to take each id from view to controller using foreach..no direct assignment..enter through the front end

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way `$this->email->to('one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com');`

You can also pass an array of email addresses Like

```
$list = array('one@example.com', 'two@example.com', 'three@example.com');


$this->email->to($list);
```

Comment: take the email ids from front end and make it array or comma separated list.

Comment: if it is a single text box and if user input  multiple email by ',' separate. then you can try this

$mail_list = $this->input->post('email');

this->email->to($mail_list);

Comment: i try this same..rite?

Comment: @Suvashsarker how to send one@example.com,two@example.com these are retrieved from data base as variable e.g  $one = one@example.com, $two = two@example.com

Comment: You can make an array like $list[] = $one;$list[] = $two;

Answer (score 2):

View

```
<input id="to_email" type="text" name="to_email[]" placeholder="To Email Address">
<input id="to_email1" type="text" name="to_email[]" placeholder="To Email Address">
<input id="to_email2" type="text" name="to_email[]" placeholder="To Email Address">
```

Controller

```
public function shopshare($userid,$shopname,$shop_id)
    {

        $from_email=$this->input->post('from_email');
        $to_email = implode(',',$this->input->get_post('to_email'));
        $subject_url=$this->input->post('url');
        $message=$this->input->post('message');
        $this->email->from($from_email);
        $this->email->to($to_email); 
        $this->email->subject($url);
        $this->email->message($message);    
        $this->email->send();

        redirect(base_url().'shop/shopDetail/'.$shop_id.'/'.$shopname);
    }
```

For single Text box

```
<input id="to_email" type="text" name="to_email" placeholder="To Email Address">
```

Controller

public function shopshare($userid,$shopname,$shop_id)
        {

```
        $from_email=$this->input->post('from_email');
        $to_email = $this->input->get_post('to_email');
        $subject_url=$this->input->post('url');
        $message=$this->input->post('message');
        $this->email->from($from_email);
        $this->email->to($to_email); 
        $this->email->subject($url);
        $this->email->message($message);    
        $this->email->send();

        redirect(base_url().'shop/shopDetail/'.$shop_id.'/'.$shopname);
    }
```

You can use valid_email() for email validation http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/email_helper.html

Comment: i have only one textbox.take each email id as comma seperated through a single textbox

Comment: then there is no problem var_dump($this->input->post('to_email')) if you will get like  xyz@gmail.com, prasd@gmail.com

Comment: i get in this way  array(1) { [0]=> string(25) "aaa@gmail.com,bb@gmailcom" }

Comment: <input id="to_email" type="text" name="to_email" placeholder="To Email Address"> use to_email only in name other wise it will be array

Comment: now get this string(27) "aaaa@gmail.com,bb@gmail.com"

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888745/sending-multiple-email-from-codeigniter) answer of stackoverflow.

```
public function shopshare($userid, $shopname, $shop_id) {

    $from_email = $this->input->post('from_email');
    $to_email = $this->input->post('to_email');
    foreach ($to_email as $key => $value) {
        $subject_url = $this->input->post('url');
        $message = $this->input->post('message');
        $this->email->from($from_email);
        $this->email->to($value);
        $this->email->subject($url);
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->send();

        $this->email->clear();
    }
    redirect(base_url() . 'shop/shopDetail/' . $shop_id . '/' . $shopname);
}
```

As per above code you need to foreach with email clear then your code work proper .